# Dynamically assign information to an "Add_Click" event on a GUI button in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to Dynamically assign information to an "Add_Click" event on a GUI button in powershell.

So an overview - I am making a GUI tool, that loads some buttons for custom "fixes" for peoples PC's. Each button is loaded from a script, and each script contains variables for information such as, Button Name, Button Icon, as well as a function that does whatever the script is meant to do.

So as per example below, I am finding the problem is where I assign the Add_Click event. I'm sorry not sure how to explain better, but it does not seem to expand the $script variable, it will save the add_click as the variable, so that when I run the program, all buttons are using whatever was last stored in the variable $script (so all the buttons look different, but run the same script).

What I want to be able to do, is have each button use an Add_Click to run whatever script is stored in $script at the time the Add_Click is assigned in the "Foreach" loop.

Example script:

```
#Button Container (Array to store all the Buttons)
$ComputerActionButtons = @()

#Get all the script files that we will load as buttons
$buttonsFileArray = Get-ChildItem  "$dir\Addin\ " | Select -ExpandProperty Name

#Load Buttons
$ButtonTempCount = 1
Foreach ($script in $buttonsFileArray){
    . $dir\Addin\$script
    Write-Host "Loading Button: $ButtonName"

    # Generate button
    $TempButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
    $TempButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,20) 
    $TempButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100) 
    $TempButton.Text = "$ButtonName"
    $TempButton.Image = $ButtonIcon
    $TempButton.TextImageRelation = "ImageAboveText"
    $TempButton.Add_Click({& $dir\Addin\$script}) 
    $ComputerActionButtons += $TempButton
}

#Add Buttons to panel
$CAButtonLoc = 20
Foreach ($button in $ComputerActionButtons){
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,$CAButtonLoc)
    $ComputerActionsPanel.Controls.Add($button)
    $CAButtonLoc = $CAButtonLoc + 120
}
```

I have been researching variables, found you can do a New-Variable and Get-Variable command to dynamically set and get variable names, but using this does not seem to help because of the original problem.

I hope I have explained this well enough, please let me know if I can give more information to help.

Thank you,

Adam

Comment: this might be worth looking into: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/22/variable-substitution-in-a-powershell-script-block.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much Anthony, chucking ".GetNewClosure()" at the end of the Add_Click line done the trick.

Your a legend :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `GetNewClosure`, which create new dynamic module, capture local scope variables to it and bind `ScriptBlock` to that module, so in fact you lose access to any function defined not in global scope, you can just store any button specific data in the button itself. `Control` base class have `Tag` property where you can store any data you want.

```
$TempButton.Tag=@{Script=$script}
$TempButton.Add_Click({param($Sender) & "$dir\Addin\$($Sender.Tag.Script)"})
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a closure over the `$script` value at the time of assignment, instead of relying on the value of `$script` at runtime.

Fortunately, all `ScriptBlock`s support this with the [`GetNewClosure()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
foreach($i in 1..3){
    $blocks += {echo $i}.GetNewClosure()
}
$blocks |Foreach-Object {$_.Invoke()}
```

which produces:

```
1
2
3
```

As opposed to

```
foreach($i in 1..3){
    $blocks += {echo $i}
}
$blocks |Foreach-Object {$_.Invoke()}
```

which produces:

```
3
3
3
```

---

What `GetNewClosure()` does is that it "captures" the variables referenced inside the ScriptBlock at that time and binds it to the local scope of the scriptblock.

This way the original `$i` variable (or `$script` for that matter) is "hidden" beneath an `$i` variable that has the same value as `$i` *used to have* - namely at the time `GetNewClosure()` was called