# How to pass a parameter when calling a function using $button.add_click(${function:functionname})

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Here is the sample image of the gui I am writting

[image]

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/7b04d67d0c1606d13035
Note: its too many characters to create here on stack overflow, so I'm using gist snippet link for the code snippet.

As of now, the code works. To test the start button, I am having it write "Hello World" to the powershell console. This is working...

Now my issue is on line #1092, I want to pass parameters of the selected objects (from the user) to the start button function.

As of now, if you click start, it will say "hell world" in your powershell console. So to test passing parameters, I am changing the following lines...

## Lines #353-356

```
        Function AD_Export_Start_Button_Click
        {
            Write-Host "Hello World"
        }
```

to

```
        Function AD_Export_Start_Button_Click
        {
            Param($selectedString)
            Write-Host $selectedString
        }
```

## And Line #1092

`$AD_Export_Start_button.add_Click(${function:AD_Export_Start_Button_Click})`

to

`$AD_Export_Start_button.add_Click(${function:AD_Export_Start_Button_Click "Hello World"})`

My problem is if I do this, nothing is written to the console window, so I know it's not working. I'm not sure why it's not working though. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically assign information to an "Add\_Click" event on a GUI button in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643256/dynamically-assign-information-to-an-add-click-event-on-a-gui-button-in-powers)

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question. My approach to utilizing the Add_Click method is passing through a function call (with parameters), where as that question is just passing through an array iterating through loops for 1 click. Or maybe I'm just not reading it correctly?

Comment: If you need only a constant values, then you probably can write it like this: `.add_Click({AD_Export_Start_Button_Click "Hello World"})`.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks :D

Comment: If the value is constant then it should be in the function rather than in the function call.