# Want to create an Event Listener for System.Window.Form.Button

Tags: .net, powershell, user-interface

I'm trying to loop through processes using get-process, then create a button for each process. This button, on_click, will remove the process, or right now display the text. Unfortunately, add_click event only displays text for the last process, like it's not attaching this event to the button at that iteration.

```
$width = 500
$dynamicFormHeight = 100
$buttonHeight = 23
$buttonWidth = 100

function GenerateForm {

    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    # System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.SetScrollState(int, $true) 

    foreach ($process in (Get-Process)) {
        $processLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $processLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size((($width / 2) - ($buttonWidth/2)), ($dynamicFormHeight - 20))
        $processLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($buttonWidth, $buttonHeight)
        $processLabel.Text = $process.ProcessName
        $inputform.Controls.Add($processLabel)

        $dynamicFormHeight += $buttonHeight
        $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size((($width / 2) + ($buttonWidth/2)), ($dynamicFormHeight - 20))
        $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($buttonWidth, $buttonHeight)
        $Button.Text = $process.ProcessName
        #$inputform.Controls.Add($Button)

        # -----PROBLEM AREA----------------
        $Button.Add_Click({
            Write-Host $Button.Text
        })
        $inputform.Controls.Add($Button)
        # -----PROBLEM AREA END----------------
    }

    
    $inputform.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($width, $dynamicFormHeight)
    $inputform.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $inputform.Add_Shown({$inputform.Activate()})
    [void] $inputform.ShowDialog()

}
GenerateForm
```

Comment: It appears that you are depending on $Button being captured in a closure when you pass the script block to Add_Click, and it also appears that PowerShell doesn't automatically create closures like that.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/closures-in-powershell/

Comment: This might also help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/get-closure-with-getnewclosure/

Comment: Why are you adding the button to the form controls twice?

Comment: Playing around with the position because although @adv12 gave some articles and narrowed the scope of my problem, I'm still having a problem with the scope, no pun intended

Comment: @Daikyu adv12 is spot on, try changing to `$Button.Add_Click({Write-Host $Button.Text}.GetNewClosure())` or `$Button.Add_Click({Write-Host $this.Text})`

Comment: What is $this? Javascript? No pun intended. @Mathias R. Jessen this works thank you very much guys

Comment: @Daikyu the runtime automatically binds the sender (in this case the button) to `$this` when it detects a scriptblock is being invoked by an event handler

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.GetNewClosure()` to the end of the `.Add_Click()` method.

Like this:

```
# -----PROBLEM AREA----------------
$Button.Add_Click({
    Write-Host $Button.Text
}.GetNewClosure())

$inputform.Controls.Add($Button)
# -----PROBLEM AREA END----------------
```

There is already a similar question on Stack Overflow: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643256/dynamically-assign-information-to-an-add-click-event-on-a-gui-button-in-powers)

Answer (score 0):

As DarkCode666 pointed out, you can use the GetNewClosure() method to create a closure and scope, but coming from a very fundamental javascript background, $this variable seems more intuitive in my opinion. @Mathias R. Jessen pointed out both

```
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

$Button.Add_Click({
    Write-Host $this.Text
})
```